# How to make different delay time each image in carousel quasar or in vue?

Tags: javascript, quasar-framework

I create carousel in quasar framework and want to make dynamic interval time each image. How to set time dynamically each image

> :autoplay="5000"

```
      navigation-icon="minimize"
      infinite
      swipeable
      style="width:100%;height:100%;"
      >
        <q-carousel-slide class="img-responsive" :ratio="0" v-for="(image, i) in images" :name="(i+1)" :key="image._id">
          <q-img @click="detailpromosi(image._id)" spinner-color="teal" :src="linkBanner+image.imageName" placeholder-src="statics/default-placeholder-1024x1024-570x321.png"/>
        </q-carousel-slide>
      </q-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by changing the `autoplay` value

Here is a fiddle with an example of 1 slide change after 1 second and the second change after 5 seconds
https://jsfiddle.net/2Lxydv5n/3/

Have a nice day